# How can I add timestamps GC log file names in a Java Service under Windows?

Tags: java, windows, tomcat, service, jvm-arguments

I've got a Java Application running against Apache Tomcat, under Windows. There are two ways of running this application - either as a Windows Service, or from a batch file to invoke Tomcat manually.

When I start the application via the batch file, I use the following to add GC logs to the JVM parameters:

```
-Xloggc=%~dp0..\logs\gc-%DATE:~-4%.%DATE:~4,2%.%DATE:~7,2%_%TIME:~0,2%.%TIME:~3,2%.%TIME:~6,2%.log
```

That causes the GC logs to be output with the date in the file name - but when run as a service, the `DATE` and `TIME` variables do not resolve correctly.

**When using a Windows Service, what variables must I use in my JVM parameters to ensure the date and time are appended to the GC logs?**

I have tried to simplify it - `gc-%DATE%.log, gc-${DATE}.log`, in all cases the variable will not resolve.

Any help is appreciated!

**Edit:** Please note that any solution *must* work when the application runs as a Windows Service. Stand alone is fine, we've got that covered. It's only when a Windows Service is used.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**EDIT - *Using Tomcat as a Windows Service***

I've installed Tomcat as a Windows service using the [documentation](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/windows-service-howto.html).

Then I've run this command line from the Tomcat bin directory :

```
"tomcat7.exe" //US//Tomcat7 ++JvmOptions=-Xloggc:gc-%DATE:~-4%.%DATE:~4,2%.%DATE:~7,2%_%TIME:~0,2%.%TIME:~3,2%.%TIME:~6,2%.log
```

*Note : `//US` is the Updating services command. `Tomcat7` is the name of the service.*

Then restart the service, now the log path is correctly resolved.

It should work assuming you have existing directories. Your expression with date expect a directory named `gc-2015.1` and create a file named `.01_13.43.35.log` (if we are the 15th of January 2015 at 13h 43min 35sec)

---

***If you are using catalina.bat***

Why it's not working? Because you suffer of a problem of delayed expansion.

You have to enable delayed expansion using `setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION` in `catalina.bat`

Then replace `%` with `!`. You will ends up with `-Xloggc="!~dp0..\logs\gc-!DATE:~-4!.!DATE:~4,2!.!DATE:~7,2!_!TIME:~0,2!.!TIME:~3,2!.!TIME:~6,2!.log"`.

Comment: It works fine when we launch the product using catalina.bat. The problem is that the Windows Service doesn't use catalina.bat at all, so whatever we put in there is flat out ignored. The question was to get this form of GC logging into the application when running as a service, not as a standalone application. Unless of course, the service somehow invokes catalina.bat?

Comment: @EvilChookie It seems it doesn't. I guess you install it as a service following tomcat doc. I realize my test was flawed because I call catalina.bat in my service but it's probably not the case for you. I'll try with the installation recommended by Tomcat and get back to you.

Comment: @EvilChookie It seems I got the solution, please see my edit. Hope it will work for you.

Comment: Now that looks promising! I'm not in a position to check it, but will let you know tomorrow. Thanks for the persistance, you at least get the bounty :)

Comment: @EvilChookie Ok thanks :) It should work, let me know!

Comment: Yep this is money.

Answer (score 8):

Using java 8 you have access to two new substitutions that is very helpful. %t and %p has been added where %t is the timestamp and %p is the process id.

-Xloggc:C:\logs\gc_%t_%p.log will result in a file named something like this in C:\logs.

```
gc_2016-08-12_10-12-29_pid7320.log
```

This feature is not documented very well. I found out about it here:
[OpenJDK Bug JDK-6950794](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-6950794)

As I also want this to work in a windows service I've added the use of this feature to the tomcat service.bat script in the following way.

```
--JvmOptions "...;-Xloggc:%CATALINA_BASE%\logs\gc-%%t.log;..."
```

Note the %%t. The extra % is needed as an escape char.

Comment: Awesome, exactly what I was looking for! Those other answers are not locale independent...

Answer (score 1):

I hope this link help you to solve it

http://tomcat.10.x6.nabble.com/gc-log-filename-variables-in-windows-td4987672.html

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not - we've already looked at this thread. We're not just adding GC logging, we're adding GC logging to a windows service.

Answer (score 1):

Even my observations were the same.

It works when we start tomcat using startup.bat and have values set for JAVA_OPTS variable in `catalina.bat`  which are related to gc logging.

It makes sense why it works because the batch interpretator
would resolve this

`-Xloggc=%~dp0..\logs\gc-%DATE:~-4%.%DATE:~4,2%.%DATE:~7,2%_%TIME:~0,2%.%TIME:~3,2%.%TIME:~6,2%.log`

to something like this

`-Xloggc:C:\logs\gc-2015.01.17_17.14.09.log`

and pass it as argument to the jvm.

Nearest what I could get was by making the following configuration using `tomcat7w.exe` which is located under bin directory.

[image: Apache Tomcat Properties]

Log files would start rolling once they reach specified size.
You can find the timestamp in the log files.

Had also tried configuring `setenv.bat` but it looks as if the `tomcat7.exe` does not use it.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried invoking a the batch file through a wrapper like [this one](http://yajsw.sourceforge.net/) ?

Edit: Also keep in mind having to use delayed expansion if necessary as @alain-janinm suggested.